# Can I use the name of a flash drive as it's directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, usb-drive

I have a flash drive named "SCHOOL". In my computer, it's registered as the F: drive. Instead of pointing to the F: drive, as it'd be different on any other computer, could I just point towards a drive named "SCHOOL" instead?

If I couldn't do this, is there a way I could always point towards this flash drive no matter how many storage devices are plugged into my computer?

Comment: are you asking `how to do this in java` or what ?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking to do this in Java.

Comment: I was waiting for your reply. Check my answer now

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. The only way I can think of is using some sort of a bat file / java class and identify each drive by name by checking out all available drive letters.

You can get all root directories (drive letters in windows) using:

```
File [] drives = File.listRoots());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Not directly but possible as following:

```
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
File[] roots = File.listRoots();
File fDrive;
for(File f : roots)
{
  String displayName = fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f);
  System.out.println(displayName);
  if(displayName.indexOf("SCHOOL") != -1)
  {
    fDrive = f;
    break;

  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for this! It worked exactly as expected, and I have my program working. MUCH appreciated!

Comment: well if you think so, mark the answer as Accepted. It will help other peoples to find the "way of doing!"